How to tell if `IsRecurrence2` Series is still Active (Lightning Experience Event Series)
I need to determine if a IsRecurrence2 event series is still actively generating new events.
There is a special method to delete an Event and all future events, but as far as I can tell, there is nothing left behind in the system that actually indicates this action has been taken.
I've looked at all the fields on all the records in the series, and I cannot find anything that indicates it was stopped.  Salesforce must be tracking this information somewhere (hopefully it's accessible).
